# Generic casting of eobject

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf-ecore

**Problem**:

I have the ecore model and i have the XML file which contains the serialized Eobjects in that.

Now i have the requirement to arrange those eobjects in the specified format in the another XML file.So when i read the xml file all objects will be of type eobject so i need to cast it to specific class to  get their functionalities.

So i need to cast for each eobject each time i read those eobjects from the file.So instead of casting it to specific class every time i want the generic class type casting declaration.

Comment: If you have a generic cast, will you still be able to obtain the class-specific functionalities?